# Reorganizing bootstrap layout - columns ordering when extending divs by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is an idea: it should be 6 boxes (three in one row), let's say it should be large viewport and each div should have class `col-lg-4`:

```
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |       |
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |       |
|   D   |   E   |   F   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
```

When user click on box, it should be toggled and expanded to take the whole row. The rest of divs should be pulled or pushed up/down like in a example below.

Assumptions:

- div extends when user click on it (it can be done by replacing class `col-lg-4` by `col-lg-12` by jquery)
- only one div can be extended at the same time

Legend:

- X - collapsed div
- X' - extended div

`A` extended:

```
 ------- ------- -------
|                       |
|           A'          |
|                       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |       |
|   B   |   C   |   D   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |
|   E   |   F   |
|       |       |
 ------- -------
```

`B` extended:

```
 ------- ------- -------
|                       |
|           B'          |
|                       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |       |
|   A   |   C   |   D   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |
|   E   |   F   |
|       |       |
 ------- -------
```

`C` extended:

```
 ------- ------- -------
|                       |
|           C'          |
|                       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |       |
|   A   |   B   |   D   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |
|   E   |   F   |
|       |       |
 ------- -------
```

`D` extended:

```
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |       |
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|                       |
|           D'          |
|                       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |
|   E   |   F   |
|       |       |
 ------- -------
```

`E` extended:

```
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |       |
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|                       |
|           E'          |
|                       |
 ------- ------- -------
|       |       |
|   D   |   F   |
|       |       |
 ------- -------
```

`F` extended:

(...)

I tried to use classes `col-lg-[push|pull]-n` but the problem seems to be moving divs up/down in rows.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: sure, here are my attempts: http://pastebin.com/Xbwrr0BZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should share what you've tried so far, but based on your description and with stackoverflow's gods mercy I will suggest this answer.

Note 2 things:

1. I used `col-xs-*` classes so it could be displayed on the snippet preview viewport. You would simply need to add/change all `col-xs-*`, to `col-md-*` and/or `col-lg-*`, whichever you wish to use.
2. To close the expanded `div` item just click it again.

```js
$(".itemA").on("click", function() {
  var isExpanded = $(this).hasClass("col-xs-12");
  //if expanded already toggle back to col-xs-4
  if (isExpanded) {
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-12");
    //insert before next item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemB");
  } else {
    //remove any other expanded item
    $(".col-xs-12").not(this).removeClass("col-xs-12").addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-12");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-4");
    //insert as first expanded item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemB");
    //place expanded item above
    $(".itemB").insertAfter(".itemA");
    //push the rest of items
    $(".itemC").insertAfter(".itemB");
    $(".itemD").insertAfter(".itemC");
    $(".itemE").insertAfter(".itemD");
    $(".itemF").insertAfter(".itemE");
  }
});
$(".itemB").on("click", function() {
  var isExpanded = $(this).hasClass("col-xs-12");
  //if expanded already toggle back to normal
  if (isExpanded) {
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-12");
    //insert before next item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemC");
  } else {
    //remove any other expanded item
    $(".col-xs-12").not(this).removeClass("col-xs-12").addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-12");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-4");
    //insert as first expanded item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemA");
    //place expanded item above
    $(".itemA").insertAfter(".itemB");
    //push the rest of items
    $(".itemC").insertAfter(".itemA");
    $(".itemD").insertAfter(".itemC");
    $(".itemE").insertAfter(".itemD");
    $(".itemF").insertAfter(".itemE");
  }
});
$(".itemC").on("click", function() {
  var isExpanded = $(this).hasClass("col-xs-12");
  //if expanded already toggle back to normal
  if (isExpanded) {
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-12");
    //insert before next item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemD");
  } else {
    //remove any other expanded item
    $(".col-xs-12").not(this).removeClass("col-xs-12").addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-12");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-4");
    //insert as first expanded item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemA");
    //place expanded item above
    $(".itemA").insertAfter(".itemC");
    //push the rest of items
    $(".itemB").insertAfter(".itemA");
    $(".itemD").insertAfter(".itemB");
    $(".itemE").insertAfter(".itemD");
    $(".itemF").insertAfter(".itemE");
  }
});

$(".itemD").on("click", function() {
  var isExpanded = $(this).hasClass("col-xs-12");
  //if expanded already toggle back to normal
  if (isExpanded) {
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-12");
    //insert before next item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemE");
  } else {
    //remove any other expanded item
    $(".col-xs-12").not(this).removeClass("col-xs-12").addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-12");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-4");
    //place expanded in second row
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemE");
    //push the rest of items
    $(".itemB").insertAfter(".itemA");
    $(".itemC").insertAfter(".itemB");
    $(".itemE").insertAfter(".itemD");
    $(".itemF").insertAfter(".itemE");
  }
});

$(".itemE").on("click", function() {
  var isExpanded = $(this).hasClass("col-xs-12");
  //if expanded already toggle back to normal
  if (isExpanded) {
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-12");
    //insert before next item
    $(this).insertBefore(".itemF");
  } else {
    //remove any other expanded item
    $(".col-xs-12").not(this).removeClass("col-xs-12").addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-12");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-4");
    //place expanded in second row
    $(this).insertAfter(".itemD");
    //push the rest of items
    $(".itemB").insertAfter(".itemA");
    $(".itemC").insertAfter(".itemB");
    $(".itemD").insertAfter(".itemE");
    $(".itemF").insertAfter(".itemD");
  }
});

$(".itemF").on("click", function() {
  var isExpanded = $(this).hasClass("col-xs-12");
  //if expanded already toggle back to normal
  if (isExpanded) {
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-12");
    //insert before next item
    $(this).insertAfter(".itemE");
  } else {
    //remove any other expanded item
    $(".col-xs-12").not(this).removeClass("col-xs-12").addClass("col-xs-4");
    $(this).addClass("col-xs-12");
    $(this).removeClass("col-xs-4");
    //place expanded in second row
    $(this).insertAfter(".itemD");
    //push the rest of items
    $(".itemB").insertAfter(".itemA");
    $(".itemC").insertAfter(".itemB");
    $(".itemD").insertAfter(".itemF");
    $(".itemE").insertAfter(".itemD");
  }
});
```

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  background: gainsboro;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.col-xs-4:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 itemA">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 itemB">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 itemC">C</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 itemD">D</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 itemE">E</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 itemF">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Next time I'll embed my code in my post. I didn't want to impose an idea for a solution. As it turns out, I reasoned in a similar manner :)

Thanks a lot! I hadn't thought about physically moving nodes in the DOM tree and unnecessarily I insisted on column ordering

Comment: This works, but is too [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions) for me!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Bootstrap push-pull, a simpler solution would be to use flexbox. This way only 1 class and order is changed via jQuery. This works alongside Bootstrap, is DRY, and can be used for an unlimited number of columns.

```
.flex {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex>div {
    display: flex;
    float: none;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
    order: 0;
}

.flex>.active {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.flex>.col-md-4').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).index();

    //set natural order
    $('.flex>.col-md-4').each(function(i,e){
        $(this).css('order',i+1);
    });

    // change active
    $('.active').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).css('order',Math.abs(idx%3-idx));
});
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/wWrUYpkwP4